# How to interpret PCA for data reduction?

Tags: r, pca, interpretation

I have 19 currency pairs like `USD.AUD`, `USD.CAD`, etc. Also 82 cross currency pairs like `AUD.CAD`, `EUR.AUD`, `EUR.CAD` etc.

When I look to their graphs, most look similar, so I want to reduce number of pairs and choose a few that represents the whole group. I calculate returns and create time series. I applied PCA but I am not sure how to interpret the results.

Any guidance is appreciated, is PCA is the right tool or I should look for others like cluster analysis, factor analysis, cointegration etc.? For example in 82 pairs should I group them like `EUR.*`, `GBP.*`?

Below is the output of my R program, how should I interpret it? Can I eliminate `KRW.USD`, `USD.CNH`, `USD.HKD` as their loadings are not correlated to first (let's say) 10 components?

```
> head(returns)
             AUD.USD      EUR.USD       GBP.USD      KRW.USD      NZD.USD
2013-06-24  0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
2013-06-25  0.0011886753 -0.003149068 -0.0008264128  0.006944472 -0.003901280
....

Importance of components:
                           Comp.1      Comp.2      Comp.3      Comp.4
Standard deviation     0.01292047 0.006641023 0.005763718 0.004634432
Proportion of Variance 0.44565430 0.117736544 0.088684302 0.057336913
Cumulative Proportion  0.44565430 0.563390849 0.652075151 0.709412064
                            Comp.5      Comp.6      Comp.7      Comp.8
Standard deviation     0.004188341 0.004066381 0.003522884 0.003427262
Proportion of Variance 0.046830128 0.044142561 0.033131261 0.031357105
Cumulative Proportion  0.756242192 0.800384752 0.833516014 0.864873118
                            Comp.9    Comp.10     Comp.11     Comp.12
Standard deviation     0.003154789 0.00295759 0.002855678 0.002798966
Proportion of Variance 0.026569419 0.02335164 0.021770068 0.020913976
Cumulative Proportion  0.891442537 0.91479418 0.936564247 0.957478223
                           Comp.13     Comp.14     Comp.15     Comp.16
Standard deviation     0.002608714 0.002233061 0.001436994 0.001043102
Proportion of Variance 0.018167468 0.013311980 0.005512535 0.002904659
Cumulative Proportion  0.975645691 0.988957670 0.994470205 0.997374864
                            Comp.17      Comp.18      Comp.19
Standard deviation     0.0009627563 1.915212e-04 1.406246e-04
Proportion of Variance 0.0024744240 9.792082e-05 5.279147e-05
Cumulative Proportion  0.9998492877 9.999472e-01 1.000000e+00
> V0$loading

Loadings:
            Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6 Comp.7 Comp.8 Comp.9 Comp.10
AUD.USD  0.275  0.390 -0.378        -0.142        -0.402  0.514 -0.286
EUR.USD  0.234 -0.238                      -0.109
GBP.USD  0.178                                           -0.370 -0.632  0.553
KRW.USD         0.111                0.126 -0.327 -0.593 -0.456  0.129 -0.450
NZD.USD  0.257  0.306 -0.515         0.139 -0.453  0.549 -0.142  0.117
USD.CAD  0.149  0.123 -0.175                0.189 -0.159         0.383  0.302
USD.CHF  0.256 -0.344        -0.150                      -0.141
USD.CNH
USD.CZK  0.288 -0.271               -0.155 -0.341         0.338  0.323  0.199
USD.DKK  0.234 -0.237                      -0.107
USD.HKD
USD.HUF  0.383         0.288 -0.243 -0.178                0.197        -0.236
USD.ILS  0.137         0.107               -0.209 -0.184 -0.201         0.205
USD.JPY  0.162 -0.281 -0.458 -0.408         0.524        -0.174        -0.147
USD.MXN  0.263  0.385  0.262  0.188 -0.579  0.272  0.203 -0.339
USD.NOK  0.324                0.607  0.329  0.289 -0.149         0.256  0.213
USD.RUB  0.224  0.382  0.404 -0.444  0.584  0.121
USD.SEK  0.325 -0.169         0.350  0.283         0.139        -0.381 -0.412
USD.SGD  0.145                      -0.102        -0.128
        Comp.11 Comp.12 Comp.13 Comp.14 Comp.15 Comp.16 Comp.17 Comp.18 Comp.19
AUD.USD                  0.194   0.149  -0.133
EUR.USD                  0.131   0.370                   0.458   0.699
GBP.USD          0.221  -0.186
KRW.USD -0.131   0.169  -0.120          -0.121
NZD.USD
USD.CAD  0.304  -0.219  -0.671   0.184
USD.CHF                  0.131   0.422           0.190  -0.721
USD.CNH                                  0.344  -0.905  -0.233
USD.CZK -0.510          -0.175  -0.368
USD.DKK                  0.130   0.369                   0.432  -0.715
USD.HKD                                                                  0.999
USD.HUF  0.562   0.442          -0.205  -0.106
USD.ILS  0.350  -0.602   0.385  -0.397
USD.JPY -0.131           0.114  -0.352                   0.123
USD.MXN -0.288                          -0.106
USD.NOK  0.102   0.325   0.275
USD.RUB -0.241
USD.SEK         -0.408  -0.362  -0.133
USD.SGD                                  0.899   0.338

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6 Comp.7 Comp.8 Comp.9
SS loadings     1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
Proportion Var  0.053  0.053  0.053  0.053  0.053  0.053  0.053  0.053  0.053
Cumulative Var  0.053  0.105  0.158  0.211  0.263  0.316  0.368  0.421  0.474
               Comp.10 Comp.11 Comp.12 Comp.13 Comp.14 Comp.15 Comp.16 Comp.17
SS loadings      1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
Proportion Var   0.053   0.053   0.053   0.053   0.053   0.053   0.053   0.053
Cumulative Var   0.526   0.579   0.632   0.684   0.737   0.789   0.842   0.895
               Comp.18 Comp.19
SS loadings      1.000   1.000
Proportion Var   0.053   0.053
Cumulative Var   0.947   1.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Principal component analysis is reducing your original dataset of p variables to k uncorrelated, linear projections of your original variables.  The first step, following the algorithm implementation, is deciding on the number of components to keep which is a somewhat subjective decision.  There are multiple ways of deciding how many to keep including

1. *cumulative proportion of explained variance criterion* - whereby you keep however many are needed to explain ~80% of total variance.
2. *Kaiser’s Rule* - whereby you retain as many PCs which have a variance larger than the average variance.  Look at your `summary` output.
3. *Scree Plot* - which is more or less a way to visualize the variance explained by each additional component and selecting the point at which the curve flattens out.  This can be done in `R` if you used `princomp` with `plot(pca_mod, type="lines")`.

Once you have determined the appropriate number of components, you have successfully reduced the dimensionality of your data!  Now, what we can do next is entirely dependent on what your goals are.  If you are looking to just explain which variables are important in the data you could then look at the individual component loading vectors.  From the loadings you present, it appears that the most important variables are USD.HUG, USD.SEK, and USD.NOK.  However, this is typically just to try and explain the PC, this may mean something significant to you or may mean nothing (hence the difficulty in PCA interpretation).  You can think of principal components as projections of variables that are immeasurable (e.g. happiness, success, etc.).  What you components actually may represent is for you to try and determine if such detail is important to you.

If you are trying to reduce the original variables, I would suggest exploring other methods such as with `stepAIC` or if you prefer a multivariate approach Partial Least Squares typically has the [Variable Importance in Projection](http://wiki.eigenvector.com/index.php?title=Vip) metric.  PCA is generally not used as a variable reduction tool in this sense.  There are many variable selection methods out there.

Now if you are just trying to get a predictive model with fewer variables (which are now your PCs) you can use PCA.  You refit your pca model with `princomp` or `prcomp` and specify the optimal number of components are use the `predict` function.   An example of this with the iris dataset has been shown in a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72839/how-to-use-r-prcomp-results-for-prediction)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I have now starting point to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Using eigenvectors can be very insight-producing, but you have to compute eigenvectors of the right matrix. PCA is based on eigenvectors of the covariance matrix. Factor analysis is based on eigenvectors of the correlation matrix. I think it is likely that you want factor analysis. (consistent with previous responder advising you to use correlations)
In either case, what you do with the eigenvectors and why are basically the same. A previous responder described that well, for PCA.

Answer (score 0):

PCA isn't the right tool here.

If you want to show that the currencies have approximately the same pairwise distribution with respect to each other, just pick a few of the currency pairs and show that the graphs look similar by putting them next to each other.

If you want to show that all the currencies have identical graphs, you might show that the distribution of all squared Pearson correlation coefficients between each pair of currencies is very narrow (low variance).