# Can PCA prediction guess the group of the new data numerically

Tags: r, pca, prediction

I'm wondering if there's a way to supply new data to a PCA prediction and have it "guess" which group the new data belongs to.

[image: Image from following code with new, predicted point (in orange) circled on plot.]

In a case like the circled area in this image there are two species plotting very close to one another, how could I predict which species a new data point belonged to (say, an unknown plant belonging to one of the three species in iris)?

In other words, if I predicted that a new data point should plot where the orange point is, but did not know the species, could I have R output a guess?

Is prediction and PCA the right way to be going about an analysis like this?

The image I've included highlights an area where this occurs using the following sample code taken from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72839/how-to-use-r-prcomp-results-for-prediction

```
    ### pca - calculated for the first 4 columns of the data set that correspond to biometric measurements ("Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width")
data(iris)

# split data into 2 parts for pca training (75%) and prediction (25%)
set.seed(1)
samp <- sample(nrow(iris), nrow(iris)*0.75)
iris.train <- iris[samp,]
iris.valid <- iris[-samp,]

# conduct PCA on training dataset
pca <- prcomp(iris.train[,1:4], retx=TRUE, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
expl.var <- round(pca$sdev^2/sum(pca$sdev^2)*100) # percent explained variance

# prediction of PCs for validation dataset
pred <- predict(pca, newdata=iris.valid[,1:4])

###Plot result
COLOR <- c(2:4)
PCH <- c(1,16)

pc <- c(1,2) # principal components to plot

png("pca_pred.png", units="in", width=5, height=4, res=200)
op <- par(mar=c(4,4,1,1), ps=10)
plot(pca$x[,pc], col=COLOR[iris.train$Species], cex=PCH[1], 
 xlab=paste0("PC ", pc[1], " (", expl.var[pc[1]], "%)"), 
 ylab=paste0("PC ", pc[2], " (", expl.var[pc[2]], "%)")
)
points(pred[,pc], col=COLOR[iris.valid$Species], pch=PCH[2])
legend("topright", legend=levels(iris$Species), fill = COLOR, border=COLOR)
legend("topleft", legend=c("training data", "validation data"), col=1, pch=PCH)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, but you're basically looking for *discriminant analysis*; see e.g. `lda` and `qda` (linear and quadratic DA) from the `MASS` package; also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis)

Comment: @BenBolker That's what I assumed, but I wasn't sure. Thank you for the clarification.